# White Space between the Title and Web Browsers

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When I use these address "file:///C:/Users/h/Desktop/test/a.html#cs", "file:///C:/Users/h/Desktop/test/a.html#chgd" or "file:///C:/Users/h/Desktop/test/a.html#wmnh" I would like them to display with white space between the title and web browsers top frame (please take a look at the picture).

Same requested result should be working for Firefox, IE and Chrome.

[image]

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link href="bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


        <script src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>            <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>        
    <script>

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        var url = document.location.toString();

        if ( url.match('#') ) {
            var hash = url.split('#')[1];

            // collapse the expanded panel
            $('#accordion .accordion-collapse').removeClass('in');

            // expand the requested panel
            $('#' + hash + '_c').addClass('in');
        }
    });


    </script>
    </head>


<body>   a<br>   a<br>   a<br>   a<br>   a<br>   a<br>   a<br>   a<br>   a<br>   a<br>   a<br>   a<br>   a<br>   a<br>   a<br>   a<br>   a<br>   a<br>   a<br>  


          <div id="accordion" class="accordion-group">                
                <div class="panel">
                    <h4 id="cs" class="accordion-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#cs_c">Child Survival: Boosting Immunity and Managing Diarrhoea</a></h4>
                    <div id="cs_c" class="accordion-collapse collapse in">
                        <p>...</p>
                        <p>aaaaa</p>
                        <p>aaaaa</p>                    
                        <p>aaaaa</p>
                        <p>aaaaa</p>        
                        <p>aaaaa</p>
                        <p>aaaaa</p>        
                        <p>aaaaa</p>
                        <p>aaaaa</p>        
                        <p>aaaaa</p>
                        <p>aaaaa</p>                    
                        <p>aaaaa</p>
                        <p>aaaaa</p>        
                        <p>aaaaa</p>
                        <p>aaaaa</p>        
                        <p>aaaaa</p>
                        <p>aaaaa</p>
                        <p>aaaaa</p>
                        <p>aaaaa</p>                    
                        <p>aaaaa</p>
                        <p>aaaaa</p>        
                        <p>aaaaa</p>
                        <p>aaaaa</p>        
                        <p>aaaaa</p>
                        <p>aaaaa</p>
                        <p>aaaaa</p>
                        <p>aaaaa</p>                    
                        <p>aaaaa</p>
                        <p>aaaaa</p>        
                        <p>aaaaa</p>
                        <p>aaaaa</p>        
                        <p>aaaaa</p>
                        <p>aaaaa</p>
                        <p>aaaaa</p>
                        <p>aaaaa</p>                    
                        <p>aaaaa</p>
                        <p>aaaaa</p>        
                        <p>aaaaa</p>
                        <p>aaaaa</p>        
                        <p>aaaaa</p>
                        <p>aaaaa</p>                        
                    </div>

                    <h4 id="chgd" class="accordion-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#chgd_c">Child Health, Growth and Development: Preventing Mental Impairment with Iodine and Iron</a></h4>
                    <div id="chgd_c" class="accordion-collapse collapse">
                        <p>...</p>
                        <p>bbbbb</p>                        
                        <p>bbbbb</p>                    
                        <p>bbbbb</p>                        
                        <p>bbbbb</p>    
                        <p>bbbbb</p>                        
                        <p>bbbbb</p>    
                        <p>bbbbb</p>                        
                        <p>bbbbb</p>    
                        <p>bbbbb</p>                        
                        <p>bbbbb</p>        
                        <p>bbbbb</p>                        
                        <p>bbbbb</p>                    
                        <p>bbbbb</p>                        
                        <p>bbbbb</p>    
                        <p>bbbbb</p>                        
                        <p>bbbbb</p>    
                        <p>bbbbb</p>                        
                        <p>bbbbb</p>    
                        <p>bbbbb</p>                        
                        <p>bbbbb</p>
                        <p>bbbbb</p>                        
                        <p>bbbbb</p>                    
                        <p>bbbbb</p>                        
                        <p>bbbbb</p>    
                        <p>bbbbb</p>                        
                        <p>bbbbb</p>    
                        <p>bbbbb</p>                        
                        <p>bbbbb</p>    
                        <p>bbbbb</p>                        
                        <p>bbbbb</p>
                        <p>bbbbb</p>                        
                        <p>bbbbb</p>                    
                        <p>bbbbb</p>                        
                        <p>bbbbb</p>    
                        <p>bbbbb</p>                        
                        <p>bbbbb</p>    
                        <p>bbbbb</p>                        
                        <p>bbbbb</p>    
                        <p>bbbbb</p>                        
                        <p>bbbbb</p>                        
                    </div>

                    <h4 id="wmnh" class="accordion-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#wmnh_c">Women’s and Newborn Survival and Health: Iron Supplementation and Food Fortification</a></h4>
                    <div id="wmnh_c" class="accordion-collapse collapse">
                        <p>...</p>
                        <p>ccccc</p>                    
                        <p>ccccc</p>
                        <p>ccccc</p>
                        <p>ccccc</p>
                        <p>ccccc</p>
                        <p>ccccc</p>                    
                        <p>ccccc</p>
                        <p>ccccc</p>
                        <p>ccccc</p>
                        <p>ccccc</p>
                        <p>ccccc</p>                    
                        <p>ccccc</p>
                        <p>ccccc</p>
                        <p>ccccc</p>
                        <p>ccccc</p>
                        <p>ccccc</p>                    
                        <p>ccccc</p>
                        <p>ccccc</p>
                        <p>ccccc</p>
                        <p>ccccc</p>
                        <p>ccccc</p>                    
                        <p>ccccc</p>
                        <p>ccccc</p>
                        <p>ccccc</p>
                        <p>ccccc</p>
                        <p>ccccc</p>                    
                        <p>ccccc</p>
                        <p>ccccc</p>
                        <p>ccccc</p>
                        <p>ccccc</p>                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>



    </body> </html>
```

Comment: No need for so many screenshots of the same thing, I have removed most of them for now.

Comment: Obviously, we can't access local files on your computer. Put your case on a live server, or make a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net).

Comment: Add padding-top to elements that have ids/are used as named anchor targets.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I copied your code locally and replaced the local CSS and JS files with CDN links

```
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>      
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Then after

```
$('#' + hash + '_c').addClass('in');
```

I added

```
setTimeout(function() {
  window.scrollBy(0,-10);
},0);
```

(After you expand the desired panel, use `scrollBy(0,-10)` to scroll up by 10 pixels for example. However, you need to let the browser finishing updating the page layout before invoking scrollBy. This can be achieved using setTimeout with a zero delay).

This works here for me, although sometimes I need to refresh the page to get your accordion code to kick in in the first place.

Comment: The code works perfectly!

Thank you guys for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Just add some CSS, for example:

```
h4 {
    margin-top: 20px;
}
```

You can add this to the `h4` tag or the entire `body` to move the whole page down. To do this, either add this content in a new CSS file and link it in the head like this:

```
<link href="mynew.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

Or you could add it directly in the page by wrapping it in a `style` tag:

```
<style>
    h4 {
        margin-top: 20px;
    }
</style>
```

An an (extreme) example to demonstrate:

```css
h4 {
  margin-top: 100px;
}
```

```html
<h4>This is the title</h4>
This is the body
```

Comment: The sourcecode doesn't work in order to get white space between web browsers top fram and and the title by pasting the address 'file:///C:/Users/h/Desktop/test/a.html#cs' in web browsers url area.

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. What did you try?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30006852/space-between-web-browsers-frame-and-the-title

Answer (score 0):

You can apply top padding to the body element to do that:

```
body {
    padding-top: 4px; /* Or whatever amount you want */
}
```

[Live Example](http://output.jsbin.com/xowuma)

Comment: The sourcecode doesn't work in order to get white space between web browsers top fram and and the title by pasting the address 'file:///C:/Users/h/Desktop/test/a.html#cs' in web browsers url area.

Comment: @HelloWorld: padding definitely works. I thought margin did too, but I guess you have to add something in addition (probably thanks to margin collapse). See the live example of padding.