# Space between web browsers frame and the title

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

When I paste the address "file:///C:/Users/h/Desktop/test/a.html#cs", "file:///C:/Users/h/Desktop/test/a.html#chgd" or "file:///C:/Users/h/Desktop/test/a.html#wmnh" in the web browsers URL field

the text 'Child Survival: Boosting Immunity and Managing Diarrhoea', 'Child Health, Growth and Development: Preventing Mental Impairment with Iodine and Iron' or 'Womenâ€™s and Newborn Survival and Health: Iron Supplementation and Food Fortification' will be displayed in the top of the web browsers frame.

Today, I would like to have space between the top of the web browser's frame and the text 'Child Survival: Boosting Immunity and Managing Diarrhoea', 'Child Health, Growth and Development: Preventing Mental Impairment with Iodine and Iron' or 'Womenâ€™s and Newborn Survival and Health: Iron Supplementation and Food Fortification'when you have pasted the address in the URL field. It should be happened automatically after you have pressed the enter button after you have pasted the URL address.

Same requested result should be working for Firefox, IE and Chrome.

[image]

[image]

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <link href="bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


        <script src="jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>            <script src="bootstrap.min.js"></script>        
    <script>

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        var url = document.location.toString();

        if ( url.match('#') ) {
            var hash = url.split('#')[1];

            // collapse the expanded panel
            $('#accordion .accordion-collapse').removeClass('in');

            // expand the requested panel
            $('#' + hash + '_c').addClass('in');
        }
    });


    </script>
    </head>


<body>   a<br>   a<br>   a<br>   a<br>   a<br>   a<br>   a<br>   a<br>   a<br>   a<br>   a<br>   a<br>   a<br>   a<br>   a<br>   a<br>   a<br>   a<br>   a<br>  


          <div id="accordion" class="accordion-group">                
                <div class="panel">
                    <h4 id="cs" class="accordion-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#cs_c">Child Survival: Boosting Immunity and Managing Diarrhoea</a></h4>
                    <div id="cs_c" class="accordion-collapse collapse in">
                        <p>...</p>
                        <p>aaaaa</p>
                        <p>aaaaa</p>                    
                        <p>aaaaa</p>
                        <p>aaaaa</p>        
                        <p>aaaaa</p>
                        <p>aaaaa</p>        
                        <p>aaaaa</p>
                        <p>aaaaa</p>        
                        <p>aaaaa</p>
                        <p>aaaaa</p>                    
                        <p>aaaaa</p>
                        <p>aaaaa</p>        
                        <p>aaaaa</p>
                        <p>aaaaa</p>        
                        <p>aaaaa</p>
                        <p>aaaaa</p>
                        <p>aaaaa</p>
                        <p>aaaaa</p>                    
                        <p>aaaaa</p>
                        <p>aaaaa</p>        
                        <p>aaaaa</p>
                        <p>aaaaa</p>        
                        <p>aaaaa</p>
                        <p>aaaaa</p>
                        <p>aaaaa</p>
                        <p>aaaaa</p>                    
                        <p>aaaaa</p>
                        <p>aaaaa</p>        
                        <p>aaaaa</p>
                        <p>aaaaa</p>        
                        <p>aaaaa</p>
                        <p>aaaaa</p>
                        <p>aaaaa</p>
                        <p>aaaaa</p>                    
                        <p>aaaaa</p>
                        <p>aaaaa</p>        
                        <p>aaaaa</p>
                        <p>aaaaa</p>        
                        <p>aaaaa</p>
                        <p>aaaaa</p>                        
                    </div>

                    <h4 id="chgd" class="accordion-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#chgd_c">Child Health, Growth and Development: Preventing Mental Impairment with Iodine and Iron</a></h4>
                    <div id="chgd_c" class="accordion-collapse collapse">
                        <p>...</p>
                        <p>bbbbb</p>                        
                        <p>bbbbb</p>                    
                        <p>bbbbb</p>                        
                        <p>bbbbb</p>    
                        <p>bbbbb</p>                        
                        <p>bbbbb</p>    
                        <p>bbbbb</p>                        
                        <p>bbbbb</p>    
                        <p>bbbbb</p>                        
                        <p>bbbbb</p>        
                        <p>bbbbb</p>                        
                        <p>bbbbb</p>                    
                        <p>bbbbb</p>                        
                        <p>bbbbb</p>    
                        <p>bbbbb</p>                        
                        <p>bbbbb</p>    
                        <p>bbbbb</p>                        
                        <p>bbbbb</p>    
                        <p>bbbbb</p>                        
                        <p>bbbbb</p>
                        <p>bbbbb</p>                        
                        <p>bbbbb</p>                    
                        <p>bbbbb</p>                        
                        <p>bbbbb</p>    
                        <p>bbbbb</p>                        
                        <p>bbbbb</p>    
                        <p>bbbbb</p>                        
                        <p>bbbbb</p>    
                        <p>bbbbb</p>                        
                        <p>bbbbb</p>
                        <p>bbbbb</p>                        
                        <p>bbbbb</p>                    
                        <p>bbbbb</p>                        
                        <p>bbbbb</p>    
                        <p>bbbbb</p>                        
                        <p>bbbbb</p>    
                        <p>bbbbb</p>                        
                        <p>bbbbb</p>    
                        <p>bbbbb</p>                        
                        <p>bbbbb</p>                        
                    </div>

                    <h4 id="wmnh" class="accordion-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#wmnh_c">Women’s and Newborn Survival and Health: Iron Supplementation and Food Fortification</a></h4>
                    <div id="wmnh_c" class="accordion-collapse collapse">
                        <p>...</p>
                        <p>ccccc</p>                    
                        <p>ccccc</p>
                        <p>ccccc</p>
                        <p>ccccc</p>
                        <p>ccccc</p>
                        <p>ccccc</p>                    
                        <p>ccccc</p>
                        <p>ccccc</p>
                        <p>ccccc</p>
                        <p>ccccc</p>
                        <p>ccccc</p>                    
                        <p>ccccc</p>
                        <p>ccccc</p>
                        <p>ccccc</p>
                        <p>ccccc</p>
                        <p>ccccc</p>                    
                        <p>ccccc</p>
                        <p>ccccc</p>
                        <p>ccccc</p>
                        <p>ccccc</p>
                        <p>ccccc</p>                    
                        <p>ccccc</p>
                        <p>ccccc</p>
                        <p>ccccc</p>
                        <p>ccccc</p>
                        <p>ccccc</p>                    
                        <p>ccccc</p>
                        <p>ccccc</p>
                        <p>ccccc</p>
                        <p>ccccc</p>                        
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>



    </body> </html>
```

Comment: Have you tried using reset.css or Normalize.css file?

Comment: Never heard about it.

Comment: How’s this question different to [your other question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30001195/1591669)?

Comment: With over 2k rep you should know not to make another question that is identical to one you [made previously](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30001195/white-space-between-the-title-and-web-browsers)

Answer (score 0):

You can add padding to the top of your `<h4>` elements, e.g.

```
  </script>
  <style>
    h4 {
      padding-top:20px;
      margin-top:-20px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
```

Or you can do it in javascript. After you expand the desired panel, use `scrollBy(0,-10)` to scroll up by 10 pixels for example. However, you need to let the browser finishing updating the page layout before invoking `scrollBy`. This can be achieved using `setTimeout` with a zero delay:

```
  $('#' + hash + '_c').addClass('in');
  setTimeout(function() {
    window.scrollBy(0,-10);
  },0);
```

Comment: The source code affect the space between  'Child Survival: Boosting Immunity and Managing Diarrhoea', 'Child Health, Growth and Development: Preventing Mental Impairment with Iodine and Iron' or 'Womenâ€™s and Newborn Survival and Health: Iron Supplementation and Food Fortification'

Comment: Give a try and test the code above.

Comment: I can imagine it does, but your source references local resources so without assembling them here, I can't see what you're seeing. You may be able to compensate with a negative margin, see my updated answer.

Comment: Is it possible to use two id in the URL and somehow use jquery to achieve the reqeusted result?

Comment: @HelloWorld not sure what you had in mind with the two id's - I've added a javascript solution that I think achieves what you need

Comment: The code doesn't work

Comment: It works here for me, although your original code for opening to the required section sometimes takes a refresh to work. I'm going to post just the javascript bit in your other question to keep things together - you should delete this one.