# Display #, not %23 in the URL

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, url, razor

Goal:
Represent '#' and not '%23' in the URL and then it should display specific info based on id.

http://localhost:49332/Home/about2?a=1&b=2&actiona=#cs

http://localhost:49332/Home/about2?a=1&b=2&actiona=%23cs

Problem:
The reason why I need # is to display specific content on the top of the web browser ([White Space between the Title and Web Browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30001195/white-space-between-the-title-and-web-browsers)) based on html's id

When I was hardcoding with "#cs" (http://localhost:49332/Home/about2?a=1&b=2&actiona=#cs) in the URL, everything was working perfectly.

I do not know how to display decode URL in order to display "#" after you have clicked the hyperlink 'test link'.

[image]

[image]

### [image]

About.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "About";
}

<hgroup class="title">
    <h1>@ViewBag.Title.</h1>
    <h2>@ViewBag.Message</h2>
</hgroup>

<article>
    <p>
        Use this area to provide additional information.
    </p>

    <p>
        Use this area to provide additional information.
    </p>

    <p>
        Use this area to provide additional information.
    </p>


    <a href="@Url.Action("about2",
            new { a=1, b=2, actiona="#cs"
            })">
      Test länk  
    </a>
</article>


                <aside>
                    <h3>Aside Title</h3>
                    <p>
                        Use this area to provide additional information.
                    </p>
                    <ul>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")</li>
                        <li>@Html.ActionLink("Contact", "Contact", "Home")</li>
                    </ul>
                </aside>
```

---

About2.cshtml

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "About2";
}

<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap-theme.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>      

<script>

    jQuery(document).ready(function() {

        var url = document.location.toString();

        if ( url.match('#') ) {
            var hash = url.split('#')[1];

            // collapse the expanded panel
            $('#accordion .accordion-collapse').removeClass('in');

            // expand the requested panel
            $('#' + hash + '_c').addClass('in');

            setTimeout(function () {
                window.scrollBy(0, -10);
            }, 0);
        }
    });


</script>

<h2>About2</h2>



a<br>   a<br>   a<br>   a<br>   a<br>   a<br>   a<br>   a<br>   a<br>   a<br>   a<br>   a<br>   a<br>   a<br>   a<br>   a<br>   a<br>   a<br>   a<br>


<div id="accordion" class="accordion-group">
    <div class="panel">
        <h4 id="cs" class="accordion-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#cs_c">Child Survival: Boosting Immunity and Managing Diarrhoea</a></h4>
        <div id="cs_c" class="accordion-collapse collapse in">
            <p>...</p>
            <p>aaaaa</p>
            <p>aaaaa</p>
            <p>aaaaa</p>
            <p>aaaaa</p>
            <p>aaaaa</p>
            <p>aaaaa</p>
            <p>aaaaa</p>
            <p>aaaaa</p>
            <p>aaaaa</p>
            <p>aaaaa</p>
            <p>aaaaa</p>
            <p>aaaaa</p>
            <p>aaaaa</p>
            <p>aaaaa</p>
            <p>aaaaa</p>
            <p>aaaaa</p>
            <p>aaaaa</p>
            <p>aaaaa</p>
            <p>aaaaa</p>
            <p>aaaaa</p>
            <p>aaaaa</p>
            <p>aaaaa</p>
            <p>aaaaa</p>
            <p>aaaaa</p>
            <p>aaaaa</p>
            <p>aaaaa</p>
            <p>aaaaa</p>
            <p>aaaaa</p>
            <p>aaaaa</p>
            <p>aaaaa</p>
            <p>aaaaa</p>
            <p>aaaaa</p>
            <p>aaaaa</p>
            <p>aaaaa</p>
            <p>aaaaa</p>
            <p>aaaaa</p>
            <p>aaaaa</p>
            <p>aaaaa</p>
            <p>aaaaa</p>
            <p>aaaaa</p>
        </div>

        <h4 id="chgd" class="accordion-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#chgd_c">Child Health, Growth and Development: Preventing Mental Impairment with Iodine and Iron</a></h4>
        <div id="chgd_c" class="accordion-collapse collapse">
            <p>...</p>
            <p>bbbbb</p>
            <p>bbbbb</p>
            <p>bbbbb</p>
            <p>bbbbb</p>
            <p>bbbbb</p>
            <p>bbbbb</p>
            <p>bbbbb</p>
            <p>bbbbb</p>
            <p>bbbbb</p>
            <p>bbbbb</p>
            <p>bbbbb</p>
            <p>bbbbb</p>
            <p>bbbbb</p>
            <p>bbbbb</p>
            <p>bbbbb</p>
            <p>bbbbb</p>
            <p>bbbbb</p>
            <p>bbbbb</p>
            <p>bbbbb</p>
            <p>bbbbb</p>
            <p>bbbbb</p>
            <p>bbbbb</p>
            <p>bbbbb</p>
            <p>bbbbb</p>
            <p>bbbbb</p>
            <p>bbbbb</p>
            <p>bbbbb</p>
            <p>bbbbb</p>
            <p>bbbbb</p>
            <p>bbbbb</p>
            <p>bbbbb</p>
            <p>bbbbb</p>
            <p>bbbbb</p>
            <p>bbbbb</p>
            <p>bbbbb</p>
            <p>bbbbb</p>
            <p>bbbbb</p>
            <p>bbbbb</p>
            <p>bbbbb</p>
            <p>bbbbb</p>
        </div>

        <h4 id="wmnh" class="accordion-title"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" data-target="#wmnh_c">Women’s and Newborn Survival and Health: Iron Supplementation and Food Fortification</a></h4>
        <div id="wmnh_c" class="accordion-collapse collapse">
            <p>...</p>
            <p>ccccc</p>
            <p>ccccc</p>
            <p>ccccc</p>
            <p>ccccc</p>
            <p>ccccc</p>
            <p>ccccc</p>
            <p>ccccc</p>
            <p>ccccc</p>
            <p>ccccc</p>
            <p>ccccc</p>
            <p>ccccc</p>
            <p>ccccc</p>
            <p>ccccc</p>
            <p>ccccc</p>
            <p>ccccc</p>
            <p>ccccc</p>
            <p>ccccc</p>
            <p>ccccc</p>
            <p>ccccc</p>
            <p>ccccc</p>
            <p>ccccc</p>
            <p>ccccc</p>
            <p>ccccc</p>
            <p>ccccc</p>
            <p>ccccc</p>
            <p>ccccc</p>
            <p>ccccc</p>
            <p>ccccc</p>
            <p>ccccc</p>
            <p>ccccc</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
public ActionResult About2(int? a, int? b, string actiona)
{

    var genres = new List<Genre>
    {
        new Genre { Name = "album"},
        new Genre { Name = "one"},
        new Genre { Name = "two"}
    };

    return View("About2", genres);            
}
```

Comment: Use one of the [Html.ActionLink overloads](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492938(v=vs.118).aspx) that accepts a fragment

Comment: What do you want as the value of the `actiona` query string parameter? Do you want it to contain `#cs`?

Comment: Stephen - Sorry, same problem occur.

Comment: John - yes, I would like actionas value to contain "#cs"

Comment: You cant have a route value with '#` in it. `#` is a fragment identifier. - use `@Html.ActionLink("Test länk", "about2", "Home", null, null, "cs", new { a = 1, b = 2 }, null)` and drop the `actiona` parameter from the method.

Comment: Stephen - Does it mean that I have to add "#" in the actionresult?

Comment: @HelloWorld, No, all you need is the parameters `a` and `b`. When the view is displayed it will scroll to page show the element with `id="cs"` (you don't need the script you have shown assuming that what your trying to do)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Stephen Muecke for your help!

> You cant have a route value with '#` in it. # is a fragment
>   identifier. - use @Html.ActionLink("Test länk", "about2", "Home",
>   null, null, "cs", new { a = 1, b = 2 }, null) and drop the actiona
>   parameter from the method.